# Magento 2 : Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time in "ups"

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, orders

I have configured ups in magento 2. When I do checkout with correct address (zipcode/country) it still give me error like this.

```
sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time
```

Why this error comes and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you verify the things with other methods?

Comment: Yes I have also tested with Table Rates and it is working fine. But when I disable table rates and enable ups, the the no quotes message appears

Comment: Have you check magento log files? Is there any things?

Comment: I have checked in debug.log and system.log but nothing in it